# How to retrieve category ID's from widget settings?

Tags: widgets

I have a widget for displaying my site's categories on the frontpage. The widget admin form has a checkbox list of categories for controlling the widget output.
What's the best way to retrieve the saved values from the category selection?
The data is saved as `$instance['widget_categories']`. So, I want to retrieve the category id's and then use them in the `include` parameter of the `get_categories()` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wg_class = new Widget_Toggle_Title();
$settings = $wg_class->get_settings();

print_r($settings);
```

Replace **Widget_Toggle_Title** class with yours.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is very simple:

```
$catsin = $instance['widget_categories'];
$child_categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby' => 'id',
  'hide_empty' => 0,
  'include' => $catsin
) );
```

This is what I originally tried to do but I made the basic error of enclosing the variable in quotes.